# Specifying Google maps iframe in CSS

Tags: html, css, google-maps, iframe

Is it possible to declare whole Google maps in CSS? I mean something like this.
 **HTML**:

```
<iframe id="map"></iframe>
```

**CSS**

```
#map {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  frameborder: 0;
  scrolling: no;
  marginheight: 0;
  marginwidth: 0;
  src: url("https://maps.google.cz/?#####");
}
```

Thank you for any help. :)

Comment: I can not think of a way to do this.  Might I ask why you want to do this though?  You could pretty easily set the src of the iframe with javascript

Comment: Code gets much cleaner when it's everything specified in CSS instead in that element. And I can change map on the all sites with just changing CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not saying this is a good idea, but you can do it using one of the not used CSS values for an iframe.

You'd still have some javascript startup code to replace the src with the correct value, but if you just added that little bit you'd be able to control your iframes src with css values.

**CSS**

```
#map1 
{
    content: "http://site1.com"; 
}
#map2
{
    content: "http://site2.com";
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //loop through all iframes, and replace the src with the css value of content
    $("iframe").each(function() {
        var url = $(this).css("content");
        //url comes with the quotes around them, so strip them off
        url = url.substr(1, url.length -2);
        $(this).attr("src", url);    
    });
});
```

Here's a mock up of what I'm talking about. 
http://jsfiddle.net/mLtWL/

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want any type of functionality in your map and you just want the image basically, you can use statics maps (image). Just construct the image you want by passing the right parameters in the url and take that and put it in css. [Check here for more](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/imageapis/)

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that in any easy way. CSS is only for controlling appearance and the source of the iframe isn't style.

You might be able to parse it using javascript (ie. parse the style and set the source that way) but then you would be using CSS in a way it wasn't designed for.